# I want to restore wordpress site backup on local host xampp

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, xampp, localhost

I made a backup of site through cpanel-ftp and also made a backup of database through phpmyadmin.

Now I copied all site files in c:\xampp\htdocs and also imported database in localhost phpadmin ( changed site url\homepage url to local host as well)

I also rechecked my database name through wp-config.php file , everything is ok there.

whenever I try to access my site it gives me following error[Error establishing a database connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhrXQ.png)

AND If i try to access installer.php then I get this error

[0B
The archive file size is currently 0B and its estimated file size should be around 142.6MB. The archive file may not have been fully downloaded to the server. If so please wait for the file to completely download and then refresh this page.

This warning is only shown when the file has more than a 10% size ratio difference from when it was originally built. Please review the file sizes to make sure the archive was downloaded to this server correctly if the download is complete.
Name:   20180403_defenceviewapartments_1ba487c8a8d788096778180403085830_archive.zip][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX4gW.png)

Comment: You don't need to run installer.php, just copy the files, import the database, edit the wp-config.php file, and set the two options in db table (which you have done).   I would suggest you check that the DB_HOST setting is set to 127.0.0.1  and not something else.  Also check the DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD are correct, obviously.  Error establishing a database connection will occur when WP can't login to the database via mysqli, which means one of those settings is wrong, or there is a networking problem, or the permissions for that user in mysql are too weak.

Answer (score 0):

Topic is quite old, but I have had the same problem, and none of the replys was right. I have solved the problem, which is actualy very easy when you know how :-)

If you have cPanel go to PHP selector --> Tab Options and set post_max_size to 512M .
Or in PHP.ini set post_max_size=512M

Thats solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Download your website folder, export your database, Put the folder in xammp and import the database, in wp_config.php change the directory to the new database, user, password. In the database changes in the wp-options table the url and home site attributes for the new link. And its done

Ps: import the data base with phpmyadmin